# PHP - Insert in database

Tags: php, postgresql

i have this problem :

in PHP i have one background process which execute some operations.
One operation is call with exec another page (ex. page2.php).

In page2.php i have simple code for insert data into database.

If i run the code for insert data into database this is OK but in the process with exec this is not function.

The code is this:

```
$timestamp= "1452765902";
$priority=1;
$file = fopen($fn, "r");
while(!feof($file)){
    $query = fgets($file);
    if($query!=""){
        $db = pg_connect("host=localhost user=postgres     password=root dbname=postgres");
        $query = "INSERT INTO     REQUEST(timestamp,idRequest,query,priority,valid)     VALUES('$timestamp',DEFAULT,'$query',$priority,'YES') ";

        //Eseguo la query
        $res = pg_exec($query);

        //chiudo la connessione
        pg_close($db);
    }
    $priority = $priority+1;
}
fclose($file);
```

Comment: You should move the `pg_connect()` line out of the loop, you are creating a new connection to the database in every line of your input file.

Comment: Where do you define `$fn`?

Comment: I move the pg_connect() line out of the loop but not work

Comment: $fn is filename passed by exec( )

Comment: if it is passed by exec, how do you retrieve it? There is nothing in the code you posted that evaluates parameters provided on the command line.

Comment: I semplify the code, but this not run again :     <?php
global $db = pg_connect("host=localhost user=postgres password=root dbname=postgres");

  $query = "INSERT INTO REQUEST(timestamp,query,priority,valid,UserId) VALUES ('1234567','asdfgg',3,'NO','qazxsw')";

       
        $res = pg_exec($query);

       
        pg_close($db);

?>